# Resizing SWF file to fit any screen resolution and NOT in browser using as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Just want to find out something... I have a `.swf` video file which I open with the normal Adobe Flash player 10. What happens is that when I open that file in a smaller screen resolution there's some parts missing (cuts it off around the edges).

How can I resize the content to fit in any screen resolution?

Answer (score 2):

stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight will let You know what is actual display window size.

You should read about Stage abilities "align" and "scaleMode":

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html

And also resize event , dispatcher after stage size change :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#event:resize

In Your case , this should help :

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```